# Soap http methods Java

Tags: java, http, web, soap

I would like to map all http's methods from within a wsdl file.

I currently have:

```
    String url = "http://ws.cdyne.com/emailverify/Emailvernotestemail.asmx";

    String wsdl = url + "?wsdl";
    WSDLParser parser = new WSDLParser();

    Definitions defs = parser.parse(wsdl);

    String targetNamespace = defs.getTargetNamespace();
    String prefix = defs.getTargetNamespacePrefix();

    defs.getServices().forEach(service -> {
        System.out.println("Service -> " + service.getName());
        service.getPorts().forEach(port -> {
            String bindingName = port.getBinding().getName();
            System.out.println("\tBinding -> " + bindingName);
            System.out.println("\tAddress -> " + port.getAddress().getLocation());

            Binding binding = defs.getBinding(bindingName);
        });
    });
```

But I would like to get the `HTTPBinding` tried in all ways but have not yet found a solution

Comment: can you specify the wsdl jar name which you used in this.

Answer (score 0):

A WSDL file is just an XML file.

Perhaps you could parse the WSDL file using XML parser to get the information you want?

1 - First use a HTTPClient to fetch the WSDL file.
2 - Then an XML Parser to read the WSDL file.

These might help:
https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/
https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/